# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program java.exe (in directory "src") - error from Executable Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

My code is working fine in Eclipse but when I am exporting from eclipse in executable jar format or by using maven, I am getting the below error:

Full error :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\myPrograms\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe" (in directory "src"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at TestAuomation.Jobs.execJob(Jobs.java:154)
    at TestAuomation.Jobs$Build_JobParams.runJob(Jobs.java:67)
    at TestAuomation.intelliPerf$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(intelliPerf.java:849)
    at TestAuomation.intelliPerf$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(intelliPerf.java:845)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
```

I am able to launch the program from jar but getting this error when trying do to some operation which invokes java -jar  .... I am running this inside my program using process builder

Please suggest what I am doing wrong

Comment: Can you give example of command which you run and full stack trace

Comment: Just to add more details: - I am trying to run some commands, for example "java -version" using process builder and then I am getting this error message. But, everything works fine inside eclipse.

Comment: @Affi update your question to show your code for creating the ProcessBuilder.  As a first guess: when run in eclipse the '.\src' directory exists, but when you run it elsewhere, '.\src' does not exist.

Comment: Thanks @dsh. I got the issue resolved. src was mistakenly set as directory for process builder causing all the issues.